# Using FullTextSqlQuery to order by date

Tags: search, fulltextsqlquery

I am using the FullTextSqlQuery object to search results from my SharePoint 2010 server with a specific query.

When I order by the created date (a new metadata property I have created myself of the type datetime), it will throw the exception “Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.”

To get around the exception I want to tick the checkbox of the property "Reduce storage requirements for text properties by using a hash for comparison" but for a datetime value it is greyed out.

Does someone have an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Something else in your query is causing the exception. As the checkbox description itself states, it **only applies to text properties**. Also, enabling this checkbox wouldn't allow you to order by in any case.

According to [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc164182.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> In the "Optimize managed property storage section", select the
>   "Reduce storage requirements for text properties by using a hash for comparison" check box if you only need
>   this property to have
>   equality/inequality comparisons. **Leave the check box cleared** if you need to
>   enable other types of comparisons
>   (such as less than, greater than, **and order by**).